# STMF4 ADC conversion seems slow

Tags: adc, stm32, timing, dma, stm32cubemx

I'm using an STM32F4 to do some 12 bit conversions.  I see from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235832/nulceo-f401-re-adc-sampling-time) that I should have hopes of getting somewhere around 1us per conversion, and since I'm doing 2 conversions, I would expect somewhere around 2us to get both channels.

However, I'm seeing from a rise and fall of a GPIO that I'm setting so I can time this whole process on a scope that I'm coming in at around 4.6us., which is over twice as long as I expected.

What I really want is a real fast sample of two OpAmp outputs at the top of a center aligned PWM to feed a FOC motor controller, so the faster and more sychronous, the better.  I need to kick off the conversion at the same time, but I also need to be sure that the sample completed, **AND** the DMA transfered the data to an array in RAM before I do any calculations based on their value.

I had originally used the ADC in continuous conversion mode, but that messed up my timers pretty bad and caused a lot of pulses to be missed, so I've resorted to just sampling when I need it, namely after a capture compare event...But this conversion is taking tooooo long.

Here's my ADC:

```
void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

    /**Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion) 
    */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_6B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 2;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
  sConfig.Rank = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_3CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  sConfig.Rank = 2;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}
```

Here's my DMA

```
void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
{
  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA2_Stream0_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn);

}


void HAL_ADC_MspInit(ADC_HandleTypeDef* adcHandle)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(adcHandle->Instance==ADC1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 0 */
    /* ADC1 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_ADC1_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**ADC1 GPIO Configuration    
    PA0-WKUP     ------> ADC1_IN0
    PA1     ------> ADC1_IN1 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* ADC1 DMA Init */
    /* ADC1 Init */
    hdma_adc1.Instance = DMA2_Stream0;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_0;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_adc1.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_WORD;
    hdma_adc1.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_WORD;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    hdma_adc1.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_adc1) != HAL_OK)
    {
      _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(adcHandle,DMA_Handle,hdma_adc1);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 1 */
  }
}
```

And, finally, here's how I'm measuring this time:

```
void Feedback_Controller(void){

  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*)ADC_Value,2);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, SAMP_Pin, SET);

  //update_PWM(ADCValue[0]);
  //HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, SAMP_Pin, RESET);
}

void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc){

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, SAMP_Pin, RESET);
  uint32_t x = ADC_Value[0];
  uint32_t y = ADC_Value[1];
  HAL_ADC_Stop_DMA(&hadc1);
}
```

And here's how things get initialized in main:

```
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim1);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim1);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
  HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
  HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
  HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_4);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using the capture event as a trigger to the ADC conversion start? I'm not sure if that is possible on your device, but I used the timers before as triggers. I'm not sure which frequency the controller is running, but a HAL can add a significant overhead.

Comment: The sampling time *for a single sample* cannot generally be used to define the sample throughput rate - the throughput will always be slower than simply adding up conversion times if software configuration is necessary; even bare metal control of the conversion will add some overhead and as Arsenal notes, a hardware abstraction layer (almost by definition) will add significant timing overhead.